# Using substring and indexOf together

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like this. I need to take after first 8 character until first comma. I tried many things but i can't figure it out? Could someone help? String comes like this.

```
"asTyped:fTestManager.Jobs.TestReplications.TestDataReplicationsJob,Version=1.0.0.0,"
```

I need convert this string to

```
"TestManager.Jobs.TestReplications.TestDataReplicationsJob"
```

I've tried

```
string tmp= "asTyped:fTestManager.Jobs.TestReplications.TestDataReplicationsJob,Version=1.0.0.0,";
int tmpLength = tmp.Substring(9).Length;
string test = tmp.Substring(tmp.IndexOf(',') - tmpLength)
```

I don't know im trying somethings like this but i can't make it out. Thank you all.

Comment: This kind of problems are easily solved using the debugger. If you do it you will notice that _tmpLength_ is equal to 74 and the index of the comma is 66.

Comment: *take after first 8 character*, you mean "take after first 9 character". The first character that is after the initial 9 is `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = "asTyped:fTestManager.Jobs.TestReplications.TestDataReplicationsJob,Version=1.0.0.0,";
string result = str.Split(',')[0].Substring(9);
```

First we split our string with `,` character with the `Split(char separator)` method. Then we get from index 9 to the end using `Substring(int startIndex)`.

Comment: Split is slow, error prone, uses more memory, and isn't needed.

Comment: It is just another way to do it, and it works.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Thank you!

Comment: indeed it might be working but as @JoelCoehoorn suggested it uses more memory because to split the string compiler has to traverse through entire string which will consume more CPU time and will be pretty inefficient if you already know that you just have to deal with first comma and nothing else. hence it is slow and memory taking.

Comment: use `.Split(new[]{','}, 2)` if you must

Comment: *It is just another way to do it, and it works* - not a great way tbh; better to identify the chars you want and perform one cut, not potentially hundreds of them, a big bunch of strings in an array, then throw all but one away and cut the first for even more string allocations.. It's like counting the number of words in a document by splitting it on space just to get the array length..

Answer (score 2):

Since we know the initial text is always the same 9 characters, we can simplify things somewhat:

```
string tmp= "asTyped:fTestManager.Jobs.TestReplications.TestDataReplicationsJob,Version=1.0.0.0,";
int startPos = 9;
int comma = tmp.IndexOf(',', startPos);
string test = tmp.Substring(startPos, comma-startPos);
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Thank you!

Comment: this should be the answer in my opinion..

Comment: string test = tmp.Substring(9, tmp.IndexOf(",")-9); swapped to this one liner

Comment: @aLy0sha you can start searching from 9 in the IndexOf.. `IndexOf(',', 9)` - a) its 9 chars you don't have to check and b) if the first 9 chars ever contained a comma it would go boom

Comment: @CaiusJard But if you do that, it still returns the index from the beginning of the string, so you still have to do the math.

Comment: In modern C#: `string test = tmp[9..tmp.IndexOf(',', 9)]` and if the end of the string is always fixed that could even be `tmp[9..^17]` I think.. Counting with a fat finger on a cellphone :D

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point about saving a little work.

Comment: You're right; it's been a loong day

Comment: @CaiusJard really thank you for giving your time. End of the string is always changing.

Comment: I gotta start getting range operations into my head as a thing that exists in C# :/